# LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express on a Window 7 machine. Two days ago, my project compiled just fine, but all the sudden it get this linker failure:

> LNK1104: cannot open file 'msvcprt.lib'

In between, I installed MS Office 2010 on that machine and Windows installed a bunch of updates, that's all. Seems like Windows / VS "lost" a file!? (how can that even happen?) What can I do about this?

Comment: It is stored in the vc\lib sub-directory of the express install directory.  Have a look if it is still there, linker says it isn't.  Which would narrow down if your disk is toast or your registry is kaput.

Comment: @HansPassant File isn't there - any idea where it went / why it's gone?

Comment: Not sure why it's too localized - it's easy to get into this situation. MSVC uses a model of inherited properties. The `LibraryPath` property typically **adds** entries, because it's usually defined as `X;Y;$(LibraryPath)`. If you miss the last entry, default libraries aren't found. And if you forget the semicolon (i.e. `X;Y$(LibraryPath)`) the macro will still be literally expanded and `Y` will be prefixed to the first entry of the old path !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be just re-installing VS. It will get all the resources for you and as long as you back up your projects (or if they're in a different folder than the default) you won't lose anything. It will be faster than trying to find that specific file.

Comment: I tried to reinstall a) the SP1 for VS2010, b) the Windows SDK 7.1 and c) Visual Studio itself. The latter thing fixed it, as you suggested. This still leaves me wondering how/why Windows removes a file that I clearly need. I'm  also quite concerned if I'll now need to repeat this procedure every few weeks... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah, well, this is something that happens every once in a while, when you install software on Windows. After using it for more than 10 years, you get used to it :) I wouldn't worry about this issue repeating, lest you plan to install other big software packages like Office.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>It seems that [these guys were able to solve it](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=15131) by installing the .NET 1.1 SDK. It's quite a silly fix, but maybe it's simpler than reinstalling Visual Studio...</strike>

Maybe it's worth trying to instal SP1 for VS2010. You might get lucky and it will fix the issue. Otherwise, you probably need to reinstall the damn thing.

Comment: No, this is heavily outdated.  Won't work for VS versions > 2003.

Comment: Oh shoot... I didn't look at the details. Thanks Hans!

Comment: I had the SP1 already installed, also the Windows SDK 7.1 and the Compiler Update.